# How can i get the SelectedRow from a list of another class

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, get, ios-4.2

I'm having a problem and im tired of searching for the answer..

I have 2 tabs, a class for each tab (tabFuncionario.h and tabObras.h), the first class (tabFuncionario) has a listview. In second class i want to get the selectedrow of the first class listview.

First Class:
tabFuncionario.h

```
   @interface tabFuncionario : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    NSArray *Names;
    NSArray *Path;
    NSArray* ListaFuncionarios;
    Funcionario* SelectedFuncionario;
}

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray*Names;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray*Path;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* ListaFuncionarios;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Funcionario* SelectedFuncionario;

+(NSString*) getSelectedFuncionarioCodigo;
```

tabFuncionario.m

```
+ (NSString*)getSelectedFuncionarioCodigo
{
    return [tabFuncionario SelectedFuncionario.codigo];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     Funcionario* func = [self.ListaFuncionarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     self.SelectedFuncionario = func;
}
```

Second Class:  tabObras.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString* Codigo = [tabFuncionario getSelectedFuncionarioCodigo];
```

The "getSelectedFuncionario" doesnt work. I'm storing the data of the selected row as an object "Funcionario" in the first class.

Do you have any sugestions? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance property from a class method:

```
+ (NSString*)getSelectedFuncionarioCodigo
{
    return [tabFuncionario SelectedFuncionario.codigo];
}
```

You can consider to use an external singleton class for store the SelectedFuncionario object and later, access it from another class.

Comment: You are right! Thats a simple way to do it but im new in Objective-C, this is my first app, so can you make a example of a singleton class? Thanks a lot @vbergae !